# Wireless with Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235

Tags: 12.04, wireless, intel-wireless, centrino

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on a Samsung Series 5 530U3C-A0J and while Ethernet works, I am having trouble with wireless LAN. It manages to establish a connection to my router without any problems, but that's it. I cannot actually use this connection, e.g. pinging my router leads to 100% packet loss, while doing the same with ethernet results in 0% loss.

Some info about the wireless chip (from lspci -nnk):

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN [8086:4060]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

I'm not allowed to answer my own question, so here's an edit:

Okay, what I did was

```
sudo rmmod iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

So it seems like n-WLAN is the problem. To permanently make this work, I added `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` as first line after the comments.

It seems to work, but can somebody tell me if this was the right way to get it working? Because wireless still needs much more time to initially establish the connection than it took with my old notebook and debian.

Comment: It is the well-known work-around for a long-standing bug in iwlwifi. What you did is correct.

Comment: @Florian R. It's encouraged to answer your own question. See here http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/ and please do! Your efforts help us all!

Comment: @ElderGeek Done, thanks for reminding me. When I asked this, I didn't have the required reputation yet.

Comment: @FlorianR. My pleasure! Welcome to the crew!

Comment: For me, the solution above did not work. I had to manually set the speed of the WiFi network to 54 Mbps on my router - then I could connect without problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Since I'm now allowed to answer my question:*

Okay, what I did to test this was:

```
sudo rmmod iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

So it seems like n-WLAN **is** the problem. To permanently make this work, I added `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` as first line after the comments.

This was confirmed by chili555's comment.