# Lubuntu 13.10 Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev-24) issue

Tags: wireless, 13.10, lubuntu

I have Asus pu500c laptop with Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev-24) network controller. My wifi works fine when my laptop is charging. But when I disconnect the charge after some time my wifi stops working. Only reconnecting to the wifi network can help for a while.

Comment: I might be wrong about this but there is a possibility that the wireless is internally connected via the USB bus. When on battery the kernel might decide to powerdown the usb busses to save power.

To check this you can disable all powersave features temporarily...the wireless should then keep on working when unplugging the powercable

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I execute `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` and uncheked 'Prefer power saving over performance' in xfce4 power manager. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Executing `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` and unchecking 'Prefer power saving over performance' in xfce4 power manager helps. This [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282449/wireless-with-intel-centrino-advanced-n-6235?rq=1) helps as well.