# Intel advanced-N 6235 Saucy not finding any wireless networks / bluetooth devices

Tags: wireless, 13.10, bluetooth, intel

I searched the Internet for my problem but did not find exactly the problem I’m facing.

I have an Intel NUC with Ubuntu 13.10 installed. Now I added a new PCIE Intel advanced-n 6235 wifi/bluetooth combo adapter. Everything seemed to be detected fine, only it won’t find any wireless networks, nor any bluetooth devices.

I already tried to uninstall the gnome-bluetooth application in favour of the bluez stack and the other way round, as I read that both packages could conflict, but no success. I also tried to disable 11n following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282449/wireless-with-intel-centrino-advanced-n-6235), with no luck. Another solution I found was to download and install the latest drivers manually, but I didn't do that yet since I thought the correct drivers should be part of the latest kernel already.

Kernel version:

```
aethy@nuke:~$ uname -r
3.11.0-13-generic
```

(Ubuntu Linux 13.10, upgraded from 13.04 with xubuntu packages installed for my wife)

aethy@nuke:~$ lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QS77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)
```

from lcpci -nn:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN [8086:4060]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

aethy@nuke:~$ dmesg | grep wifi

```
[    3.058595] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    3.058671] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[    3.083353] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[    3.148594] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[    3.148599] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[    3.148603] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[    3.148606] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_P2P disabled
[    3.148611] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6235 AGN, REV=0xB0
[    3.149582] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[    4.349943] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[    4.357260] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0
[    4.631726] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[    4.638561] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0
```

aethy@nuke:~$ lsmod | grep wifi

```
iwlwifi               143578  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              401436  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
```

aethy@nuke:~$ ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ec:a8:6b:f1:fb:45  
      inet addr:94.227.41.23  Bcast:94.227.41.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::eea8:6bff:fef1:fb45/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1629223 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:611522 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:2378810676 (2.3 GB)  TX bytes:61283015 (61.2 MB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f7d00000-f7d20000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:25073 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:25073 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:2683709 (2.6 MB)  TX bytes:2683709 (2.6 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:d9:87:0a:ee:f7  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

aethy@nuke:~$ iwconfig

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

aethy@nuke:~$ iwlist scanning

```
wlan0     No scan results

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

Bluetooth packages installed:

```
aethy@nuke:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep blue
blueman                        install
bluemon                        install
bluetooth                    install
bluez                        install
bluez-alsa:i386                    install
bluez-cups                    install
bluez-gstreamer                    install
bluez-hcidump                    install
bluez-tools                    install
gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0            install
gnome-bluetooth                    install
indicator-bluetooth                install
libbluetooth3:i386                install
libgnome-bluetooth11                install
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth            install
python-bluez                    install
```

No bluetooth devices found (while my gsm was visible and my stereo was pairing)

```
aethy@nuke:~$ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
aethy@nuke:~$
```

Comment: May I also see: rfkill list all and: dmesg |  grep iwl

Comment: Have you tried these instructions? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1996768

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the very same issue with my NUC.

3.8.0-19

Re: Bios; when changing the power setting on the NUC, it seems to effect the visibility of bluetooth devices and can pair. 
However this is only works temporarily, as the device will eventually drop. In my case this is a keyboard.

I'm thinking that it's either the firmware on the card or a poorly written bios.

Comment: Sorry for the late response... what power option exactly did you change? When I put my phone in a 1cm range of the NUC, it finds the device when scanning, but connecting still does not work. I'm trying all different power options but do not see much difference so far.

Comment: I've got a home-built using an MSI board with the same problem. At first I thought it was because I didn't have any antenna, but I added that and still same deal. Using my phone as hotspot 10cm away works, but nothing else. Bluetooth works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Install ndiswrapper

`sudo aptitude install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-modules-1.9 ndiswrapper-utils-1.9`

Install the WiFi driver (from Windows):

sudo ndiswrapper -i yourdriver.inf

Check the driver is working:

`sudo ndiswrapper -l`

Load the module:

`sudo depmod -a`

`sudo modprobe ndiswrapper`

Configure modprobe so that it loads ndiswrapper:

`sudo ndiswrapper -m`

Edit the modules to add ndiswrapper at the end:

`sudo gedit /etc/modules`

Remember to add **ndiswrapper** at the end.

Hope you now have your WiFi back!