# Bodhi/Lubuntu 18.04/19.04 - Error loading driver for Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 Wireless - Device not ready / Failed to load firmware chunk!

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, iwlwifi

Trying to get something working on a SFF box for CNC control.  Can't get wireless to work under Bodhi 5.0.0 or Lubuntu 18.04, or Lubuntu 19.04.  (Hardware is a [LogicSupply AG150](https://www.logicsupply.com/ag150/))

I've verified that I'm using the latest driver version for the hardware from https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi

The only other instance of the exact same problem I found is for completely different hardware/os.  https://community.nxp.com/thread/336121

I've also tried the 'well-known work-around' from https://askubuntu.com/a/462410/970126 of

```
sudo rmmod iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Here's the actual problem as shown by `dmesg` (last 3 lines):

```
[   44.072759] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6235 AGN, REV=0xB0
[   44.139621] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   44.566744] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   46.224888] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   46.238035] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0
[   51.424070] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[   51.424085] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[   51.424094] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[   51.424152] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: 088e8086 00100406 02800024 00000010 40500004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   51.424165] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 40608086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 0000010a
[   51.424173] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[   51.424228] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: 00484b00 00000040 20000000 08000000 00000000 00000000 00000030 00000000
[   51.424239] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: 00000009 080003c5 000000b0 00000000 90000801 00030001 80008040 00080044
[   51.424251] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
[   51.424288] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: 14010001 00004000 00000000 00062011 00002000 00002000 0000000e 00000000
[   51.424297] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   51.424305] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.3) config registers:
[   51.424339] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.3: 00000000: 27d68086 00100007 06040002 00810010 00000000 00000000 00020200 20004040
[   51.424351] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.3: 00000020: 40504050 40c140b1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 00000000 000404ff
[   51.424364] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[   51.436122] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   51.436155] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
```

Here are the `wireless-info` logs from all 3 installs.

- Bodhi 5.0.0 https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NQ2WMpdhcc/
- Lubuntu 18.04 https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/J4SJsZdM7g/
- Lubuntu 19.04 https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Z2wW26sfv2/

Where do I look or what do I try next to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that there are but three possibilities. First, does the required firmware actually exist on your system? According to Intel's own site, the needed firmware is iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode. Please see: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html

Please check your system:

```
cd /lib/firmware && ls | grep iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
```

Does the file exist?

The second possibility is that the file is somehow corrupted. Let's check:

```
md5sum iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
```

My system returns 1f1763dfd472a487c3d61eac0a12b766. If yours returns the same, then I doubt that the firmware is corrupted.

In fact, I doubt that, on three installations across two different Linux distributions, that the firmware is always missing and/or always corrupted. That leads to the third possibility, That the hardware, that is, the card itself, is either not seated properly in its slot or else is electrically defective.